# C# How to read commit time with libgit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I am trying to list all commits in repository, their Authors and date of commit using libgit2Sharp, but the commit object doesn't have property of date/time where the commit was created.

```
 using (var repo = new Repository(path))
 {
     ///get commits from all branches, not just master
     var commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(new CommitFilter { Since = repo.Refs });

     //here I can access commit's author, but not time
     commits.Select(com => new { Author = com.Author.Name, Date = com.???
  }
```

I didn't find any documentation of the libgit2sharp project, on the official page it says:

> Let's put it simply: we currently lack proper documentation. Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated ;-)

How can I access commit's time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The date a commit was authored or committed is part of the [`Signature`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Signature.cs#L71), along side the name and email address.  The `When` member of the signature is a [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it was authored or committed.  If you're looking for the authorship date in your example, then you want:

```
com.Author.When
```